# #Error in TextBox inside Rectangle

Tags: reporting-services

Today I ran into a strange problem in a report in SSRS. In the report I have one rectangle, in which I have some textboxes. Textboxes contains either static text or fields from datasets. One which shows static text work properly, but the one with values from dataset, shows me "#Error".

If I pull that suspicious textbox outside of the rectangle, then it works properly.

What can be the problem?

Comment: I must add that I have few datasets, both shared and embedded, and only from embedded dataset i can show values, while from shared datasets i constantly getting error.

Comment: You're not providing enough info for us to answer your question. The "#Error" should also provide feedback on *what* the problem is. In fact, once you see the additional info it may very well be easy to fix your problem. (Also note that you can edit your question to add info, no need to use comments for that.)

Comment: Ok, Jeroen, thanks for suggestion, I'm very new to StackOverflow, so I need some time to catch all things about posting and editing :) I tried today to catch what cause problem to see error, and maybe I got some idea. When I tried to preview some field value from embedded dataset it works properly, in Preview mode I see given value. When I put some field from shared dataset into textbox expression, in Preview mode I see only famous #Error, in place of textbox. I suppose that problem is with shared dataset, but cannot be sure.

Comment: Can you provide the expression code for the textbox in question

Comment: @veljasije Don't worry about being new, and thanks for taking the time to "catch all things"! SO is a bit different from forums, for one you can always click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13514111/edit) link below your question to improve it and add details requested in comments. This helps others answer your question, and helps people landing here through search queries to see if they have a similar question or not.

Comment: Code for expression is quite simple: **=Fields!SomeField.Value**, and to mention, this field is from dataset. But, today i found something. When that textbox is alone, whether is inside or outside of rectangle, then shows error, but if I add one more textbox with same expression, whether inside or outside of rectangle, then first show error, other is valid. Somehow i doubt that problem is something in positioning. Example: five textboxes with same values, first is with error, others is valid, when I move first textbox to the end, that is valid, but next first is with error.